# onNext not called - RxJava

Tags: android, rx-android

I'm using RxAndroid for my app to send a request to the backend and handle the result.

```
public Observable<Response> getBrands() {
    return new Observable<Response>() {
        @Override
        protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super Response> observer) {
            RequestHelper.GetRequest("getbrands");
        }
    };
}
public void GetBrands(){
    getBrands().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response value) {
            Log.w("Reactive",value.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Yaaaaay request 5alas",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.w("response brands= "+e.toString(),"MyTAG");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
}
```

RequestHelper.GetRequest("getbrands") is successfully called (Checked backend logs, it's called and returns the response.

the problem is onNext not getting called at all, neither the log or the toast shows up.
Anyone knows why ?

EDIT: i'm using this in a fragment where GetBrands() is called in oncreateview

Answer (score 0):

Just changed my observable function to

```
public Observable<Response> getBrands() {
       return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Response>() {
            @Override
            public Response call() throws Exception {
                return RequestHelper.GetRequest("getbrands");
            }
        });
}
```

it's working now